# Sequelize v4 recordInstance.Model undefined

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

In v3 I can get the model of any record:
`record.Model`
http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/api/instance/#model-model

What is the v4 analog?

Answer (score 0):

From `v4`, the models become es6 classes.
This is the way you should access the model:

```
record.constructor
```